# How can I have rotated log files without a numbered suffix using Linux logrotate?

Tags: linux, compression, logrotate

I have on my server more file rotate, but when I want to compress it, i Have an extension `1.gz`, but I just want `.gz`

These files are automatically rotate by the application:

```
server.log.2023-03-16
server.log.2023-03-15
server.log.2023-03-14
```

My result:

```
server.log.2023-03-16.1.gz
server.log.2023-03-15.1.gz
server.log.2023-03-14.1.gz
```

I want:

```
server.log.2023-03-16.gz
server.log.2023-03-15.gz
server.log.2023-03-14.gz
```

My logrotate file:

```
#/var/log/application/*/server*.log.* {
  daily
  rotate 14
  compress
  delaycompress
  missingok
}
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: logrotate numbers logs, so it can rotate. It's not quite clear what you want? Don't you want to preserve older logs? If you don't want to preserve older logs, why compress them?

Comment: I Marcus,I just want to compress logs.

Comment: Then why use `logrotate`? You could just run `gzip` on all the relevant log files.

Answer (score -1):

if you want your rotated log file to looks like -- > `server.log.2023-03-16.gz`
just add

```
dateext
dateformat .%Y-%m-%d
```

to your logrotate file.

Comment: Note that the user's `logrotate` pattern matches the compressed log files. You may want to amend your answer to take this into account.

Comment: Also OP's logs _already_ have the date suffix added by the application that does the logging, so this will probably result in a file like `server.log.2023-03-16.2023-03-16.gz`